# How to expand a Div smoothly?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that expands depending on the result of the select, it is with the height set to "auto". I want to make this expansion soft, it is very hard.

Script used to expand and collapse the div::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowHideDIV(NomeDIV, Valor) {
            Valor = document.getElementById("Lista").value;
            if (Valor == "Sim") {
                document.getElementById(NomeDIV).style.display = "block";
            } else {
                document.getElementById(NomeDIV).style.display = "none";
            }
        }
</script>
```

Parent div (to which I want to put the effect):

```
<div class="bgCotar"></div>
```

Select (responsible for the expansion of Parent div):

```
<div class="campo" id="campo4">
   <label>Incluir Dependentes?</label><br />
   <select name="Lista" size="1" id="Lista"
   onChange="ShowHideDIV('CampoOculto','Sim');">
      <option value="0">Selecione...</option>
      <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
      <option value="Nao">Não</option>
   </select>                                     
</div>
```

An example of what I'm wondering:
http://www.maujor.com/blog/pg_apoio/jquery-toggle-texto-exemplo.html

Sorry for my bad English, my language is Portuguese.

Comment: give up javascript, use jquery instead for these kind of operations. It is very easy.

Comment: I'm learning jQuery, still am not able to write this. This javascript code up there I got ready for a tutorial ...

Answer (score 1):

The site you showed uses jQuery - slideToggle functionality - http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/ . Use this to animate your page

Answer (score 0):

You must take a look at jquery. It has some good effects to do what you want to. Also, again, you can use jquery's animate() function.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_toggle

Comment: as a w3fool, I have learned much information from w3schools.com as a starting point.